# doSNOW/foreach Performance Issues

Tags: performance, r, parallel-processing

I have a loop which is loading decent size files around 5MB each and than running some computations on them.  I need to load 500-1000 of them.  Seems like an easy job for foreach.

I am doing this but the performance of doSNOW seems to be horrendous.

I found this post and this fellow seems to have had the same issues:

http://statsadventure.blogspot.com/2012/06/performance-with-foreach-dosnow-and.html

So a couple of questions.

1. Is there an alternative to doSnow?  I realize there is doMC but I am running windows.
2. Is doMC on linux that much faster than doSNOW?
3. Is there anyway to output to screen from a worker so I can at least get some sort of idea how my job is progressing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The author of that blog post appears to solve his problem at the end: that doesn't help in your case?

Comment: I thought that my case would be fine since each file takes a few seconds to load.  That is not the case.  I am currently making an attempt using sfLapply with snowfall. But the stability is TERRIBLE.  R keeps on crashing.

Comment: *Parallel* attempts to load *different* files may result in very bad performance. So, if the loading of the files takes a significant amount of the total time, you're probably much better off reading them sequentially. If not, using a load balanced parallelization may help (e.g. `parallel::clusterApplyLB` or its snowfall analogue). If the parallelization is not load balanced, you'll stay in the situation that all threads ask different files from the HDD at the same time.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you prefer the doXXX over e.g.  `parallel::clusterApply`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments @cbeleites can you elaborate on why I need to use load balancing?

Comment: @davewolfs: I put it as an answer because of the plots. I don't know whether this answers your question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple threads trying to access different files on the hard disk can lead to very bad performance.

However, load balanced parallelization may still lead to improvement if enough time goes into calculations: the nodes will get out of synchronization thus hard disk requests will come in one after the other instead of all at the same time.

Here's a simple example of `snow::clusterApply` vs the load balanced `snow::clusterApplyLB`.  I use snow instead of parallel as it provides timing and plotting:

```
library (snow)
system(sprintf('taskset -p 0xffffffff %d', Sys.getpid()))
cl <- makeSOCKcluster (rep ("localhost", 2))

times <- sample (1:6) / 4
times
## [1] 1.50 0.25 0.75 1.00 0.50 1.25

t <- snow.time (l <- clusterApply (cl, times, function (x) Sys.sleep (x)))
plot (t, main = "\n\nclusterApply") 
for (i in 1 : 2)
  points (t$data[[i]][,"send_start"], rep (i, 3), pch = 20, cex = 2)
```

[image: clusterApply]

```
tlb <- snow.time (l <- clusterApplyLB (cl, times, function (x) Sys.sleep (x)))
plot (tlb, main = "\n\nclusterApplyLB")
for (i in 1 : 2)
  points (tlb$data[[i]][,"send_start"], rep (i, 3), pch = 20, cex = 2)
```

[image: clusterApplyLB]

The black dots mark the start of a new function call. If the function starts with loading the file, all nodes will always try to access the hard disk at the same time with `clusterApply` because the cluster waits for all nodes to return results before dealing out the new round of tasks. With `clusterApplyLB`, the next task is handed out as soon as a node returned the result. Even if the tasks take basically the same time, they will get out of synchronization rather fast and the file loading will not be exactly at the same time.

(I don't know whether this is the actual problem, though)

Comment: Wht's the difference between snowfall and doSnow?

Comment: @skan: `snowfall` is an additional layer on top of snow. It allows to write e.g. programs that can use a cluster if one is available, but if not, they'll work sequentiall. See the package description and vignette available at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html. This is rather old stuff, and the parallel `package` is now around, which is base R. So in practice, I'd now try to work with `parallel` unless there are very specific additonal needs.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then I should learn parallel instead of doSnow as well?
Anyway what if I want to distribute the computation not only among processores in the same computer but also among different computers in a cluster?